# Would like to withdraw my flag for closure in favor of vote to close

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close

About a month ago, when I had less than 3k rep (on stackoverflow) I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672395/python-making-codes-continue-on-different-line) as a duplicate, a copy and paste of a previous one by the same author. The flag hasn't been deal with (no problem there, stackoverflow is v busy), and I now have more than 3k rep and I'd like to be able to vote to close, so that it goes into the close queue and gets dealt with by the community.

But when I choose the close option I get "You flagged this question for closure Mar 31 at 19:39". It doesn't seem unreasonable that my flag should be withdrawn and replaced with a vote to close. This isn't just for the situation where a sub 3k user becomes a 3k user: I understand something similar might occur if I'd used up my close votes for the day.

Comment: I casted a close vote for you. If it gets another one it will show up in the close queue...

Comment: same here. in da q